# Why does Google custom search has HTML elements in snippet response?

Tags: google-custom-search

We are using the Google custom search XML API and in our response we get html elements. For example:

```
<S> 19 Jan 2015 <b>...</b> Edinburgh Evening News <b>Susan Morrison</b>. “How many <br> folk singers does it take to change a lightbulb? ;...</S>
```

The using of `<b>` tag is used to highlight the words that the user searched for, but why is in the response the `<br>` tags? These tags are breaking our layout.

Can they be removed at the runtime using javascript or are they mandatory for and we are not allowed to remove them?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking why they are there (only a google dev can answer that), or are you asking how to remove them, or are you asking if you are _allowed_ to remove them?

Comment: Just why they are there (I'm guessing it is a purpose) and if we are allowed to remove them. The removing part is not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this 'effect' too:

Using the Custom Search Element API 2.0 (JavaScript widget https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element) the returned snippet emphasizes instances of the search query with `<b>` tags, but doesn't introduce (arbitrary?) line break `<br>` tags.

Using the Custom Search JSON/Atom API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview), the returned htmlSnippet contains the same `<b>` tags, but introduces troublesome `<br>` tags too.

I'm sure it is fine to remove the `<br>` tags; I cannot think of why they have been introduced in one API and not the other.